# CodeIgniter join from same table

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I have one table called guests.

A guest can be `guest` or a `plus_one`.

If it's a `plus_one` this `plus_one` is connected to a `guest` by a master_id. The column `id` is auto incrementing.

Table

```
id   master_id  type
1    1          guest
2    1          plus_one
3    3          guest
4    3          plus_one
5    5          guest
6    6          guest
```

Expected result from query is an array with an array for each guest, and if that guest has a plus_one attached via the master_id it has that as a sub array.

Taking the table above, it should look like this (simplified):

```
[0]
  ['id'] => 1
  ['master_id'] => 1
  ['type'] => guest
  ['plus_one'] => // This is a sub array
    ['id'] => 2
    ['master_id'] => 1
[1]
  ['id'] => 3
  ['master_id'] => 3
  ['type'] => guest
  ['plus_one'] => // This is a sub array
    ['id'] => 4
    ['master_id'] => 3
[2]
  ['id'] => 5
  ['master_id'] => 5
  ['type'] => guest
[3]
  ['id'] => 6
  ['master_id'] => 6
  ['type'] => guest
```

I think I need to do a self join, but I can't figure out how and also can't figure out how to do get the sub array as a result. What I have tried:

```
$this->db->from('guests a');

$this->db->join('guests b', 'a.master_id = b.master_id', 'left outer');

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant get that from only one query. Queries returns X rows with X columns. But it can't be expressed as a multidimensional array.

You have two options here:

1: Get the list of guests (including plus_one) then iterate it (in a for each) and if its "plus_one" call the method to bring its child.

Or... (Not that pretty)

2: Join your table with itself (like you were doing) and set an alias for every child property.
Something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.*, 
    b.id as plus_one_id,
    b.master_id as plus_one_master_id
```

But again, the result here wouldn't be a multidimensional array. Just a row with all the data. (Or nulls). I'd go for the first.